# Integrability of Airy function

Tags: real-analysis

I work with well known *Airy function* given for evey $x\in R$ by 
$$Ai(x) := \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_R e^{i(x\xi + \xi^3)} \, d\xi = \lim_{K\to+\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-K}^K e^{i(x\xi + \xi^3)} \, d\xi.$$

My question is, how to prove that the intergral $\int_R Ai(x) \, dx$ exists, or in the other words, how to prove the existence of the limit
$$\lim_{K\to+\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-K}^K Ai(x) \, dx$$
?

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotics for the Airy function are known (see the [first formula here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Asymptotic_formulae)). These asymptotics immediately prove that the function is integrable. (For that matter, so does the existence of its Fourier transform, further down that page.)

Comment: I agree but, these asymptotic formula does not work in the case when $|Arg(z)| = \pi$. Therefore we cannot use it to prove of the existence of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 Ai(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. Okay, I suggest then finding a source that computes the Fourier transform of Ai$(x)$ - that is stronger than integrability. Alternatively, further down on that Wikipedia page is a formula relating Ai$(x)$ to Bessel functions when $x<0$, so you can look for ways to show that the Bessel functions are integrable.

Comment: Note that Ai$(x)$ is not absolutely integrable on $(-\infty,0)$, I believe; rather; it's integrable because of oscillations. One way to handle that is to integrate by parts. For example, when $x>0$, one can do the following transformation:

Comment: \begin{align*}
\mathop{\rm Ai}(x) &= \frac1\pi \int_0^\infty \cos\bigg( \frac{t^3}3 + xt \bigg) \,dx \\
&= \frac1\pi \int_0^\infty \frac1{t^2+x} \cdot (t^2+x) \cos\bigg( \frac{t^3}3 + xt \bigg) \,dx \\
&= \frac1\pi \bigg( \frac{\sin( t^3/3 + xt )}{t^2+x} \bigg|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty \frac{2t}{(t^2+x)^2} \cdot \sin\bigg( \frac{t^3}3 + xt \bigg) \,dx \bigg) \\
&= \frac1\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{2t}{(t^2+x)^2} \cdot \sin\bigg( \frac{t^3}3 + xt \bigg) \,dx .
\end{align*}
Since $|\sin(\cdot)|\le1$, this leads to a bound for Ai$(x)$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The existence $\int_1^\infty A_i (x) dx$ is straightforward via the following asymptotics 
$$\text{Ai}(x) \sim \frac{\exp(-\frac{2}{3} x^{3/2})}{x^{1/4}}, \quad x \to +\infty$$ 
The existence of $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \text{Ai}(x) dx$ is less obvious, despite we have the asymptotics $x \to -\infty$
\begin{align*}
\text{Ai}(x) &\sim \frac{\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\Big)}{x^{1/4}}\\
\text{Ai}'(x) &\sim -\frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\Big)}{x^{5/4}} - x^{1/4}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2}{3} x^{3/2}\Big)
\end{align*}

The integral does not converge absolutely. To prove the convergence, one can use the property
$$\text{Ai}''(x) = x \text{Ai}(x).$$
One has via integration by part
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \text{Ai}(x) dx &= \int_{-\infty} ^{-1} \frac{\text{Ai}''(x)}{x} dx\\
&= -\text{Ai}'(-1) + \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{\text{Ai}'(x)}{x^2} dx
\end{align*} 
The second integral now converges absolutely.